# App Store: "app is preparing" mode

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I know this is a long shot but do you know if there is a chance put the app to AppStore im something like "preparing mode"? I mean it would be there, users could find it but instead of Download button there would be "in 7 days" or something.

The reason for that is that we're under extreme pressure from client to launch the app tomorrow and there's no chance how to make it in usual way (we're still testing the build and working on bug fixes).

Thanks a lot :)
Kuba

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, or even release any app which says Demo app.

The best you can do is to release it at the store with those features which are ready to be released. Work on known bugs as new features which you can include in next release. If you want to release it for Closed user group "TestFlight" of  "[iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/)" can help you.

You can set the release date through iTunes connect as well, but that will not show your app to users until that is released.